# Ionic show {{ data.name }} only after data is available (from HTTP)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am creating an Ionic 4 app.

I load an object from my API wie HTTP and then show it in the view.

```
{{ data.name }}
```

Since the HTTP request is async, when the page loads the data object is not yet loaded and the data.name is undefined which returns an error.

I could do some kind of `<span *ngIf="data">{{ data.name }}</span>` but this does not seem to be the best solution.

Is there a best practice for this situation?

Comment: initialize the variable, so that `data` won't be undefined. Or use safe navigation operator.

Comment: Wrap it in an html element and use `*ngIf` or you use `?` operator `{{ data?.name }}`

Comment: `<span *ngIf="data">{{ data.name | async }}</span>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use async pipe like this way :

```
{{ data.name | async}}
```

Comment: From my understanding, data is not an observable, anyway, if it were - this wouldn't work anyway.